# Vue-cli-service doesn't recognize my node version

Tags: node.js, vue-cli

I just started working on a Vue project and for some reason `vue-cli-service` doesn't recognize my actual node version. I use `n` to manage my versions, but no matter which one I choose vue thinks I use version 11.13.0. I checked for a leftover node v11 executable in my path but it's not there. I also don't have node installed via brew.

I'm on macOS 12 with a zsh shell. Any ideas where this old node version may come from? Some default mac settings maybe?

```
┌ marc in marc/projects/ystagram-fr at 14:48 :git(feature/YST-5-frontend)
└(ystagram-fr) npm run serve

> y-stagram-frontend@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

 ERROR  You are using Node v11.13.0, but vue-cli-service requires Node ^12.0.0 || >= 14.0.0.
        Please upgrade your Node version.
┌ marc in marc/projects/ystagram-fr at 14:49 :git(feature/YST-5-frontend)
└(ystagram-fr) node -v && npm -v
v18.1.0
8.8.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the problem! As I logged `process` in the `@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js` file I saw that it uses the node version from the global node_modules, which was for some reason 11.13

```
  argv:
   [ '/Users/marc/node_modules/node/bin/node',
     '/Users/marc/projects/y-stagram-frontend/node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service',
     'serve' ],
```

I still don't know why it doesn't use by default the global node executable, as on another machine it does, but a temp fix was to run `npm i node@{version >= 14.0}`.

Comment: how did you solve that , please update more detail